# mongodb count equal object

Tags: ruby, mongodb, count

I have a MongoDB database with documents that contain a filter field. The documents looks like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("503208f5b5db0135387d9249"),
   "name": "name1",
   "filter": "facebook"
}          {
   "_id": ObjectId("503208f5b5db0135387d9249"),
   "name": "name2",
   "filter": "twitter"
}  
{
   "_id": ObjectId("503208f5b5db0135387d9249"),
   "name": "name3",
   "filter": "twitter"
}
```

And I want to count by type. This example should be like this:

```
facebook => 1, twitter => 2
```

With ruby code, counting is very slow.

The filter is a String which could be anything. E.g:

```
{facebook : 1203, twitter : 201, wherever : 200, othertype : 400}
```

I am using mongo mapper (ruby driver).

==============
EDIT 3

Finally it's working. here's the code for ruby driver:

```
def map  
    'function(){  
        emit(this.plataforma, 1);
    }'  
end   
def reduce   
    '
    function(prev, current) {  
        var n = 0;
        current.forEach(function(v){
            n+=v;
        });
        return n; 
    }'
end 

def build  
    Mention.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, :query => {})  
end
```

Comment: what version of mongo are you using?

Comment: You can use the aggregation framework with `$match` and `$sum` or a MR or pre-aggregation here

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your MongoDB version. With that version you can only do either a Map Reduce or pre-aggregation to solve your problem. I would strongly advise upgrading your database since 1.6.3 is a very old version and lacking a lot of new features and better query handling etc.

Comment: filter can be anything, it is a string .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/count_tags/

Where by it shows how you could run an MR like so:

```
var map = function(){
    emit(this.filter,1);
}

var reduce  = function(previous,current){
    var count = 0;

    for (index in current) {
        count += current[index];
    }

    return count;
}
```

Which will then output, to another collection (or inline if you want) documents of the format:

```
{
    _id: facebook,
    value: 1,
    _id: twitter,
    value: 2
}
```

This is written in MongoDBs console language which is JS. MongoDB has a built in JavaScript parser (spidermonkey) which can parse MR functions. From Ruby you would encapsulate your functions like so:

```
map = BSON::Code.new "function() { emit(this.filter, 1); }"
```

And then run the MR like so:

```
col.map_reduce(map, reduce,
        {
            :out => 'summary_collection',
            :raw => true
        }
      )
```

And then you would just query summary collection for that filter by supplying the string representation as the `_id` or do a simple `find()` to get all results.

Comment: what is this code? I dont't understand. this query will run to more than 200.000 documents, whould be slow?

Comment: @RodrigoDias This code will not work in realtime unlike an SQL query, the aggregation framework could do that but not map reduce. You would need to output this to a summary collection which you would store as a cache to read from updating the MR (maybe incrementally) once every 5 mins or so. Of course you could still do pre-aggregation which will solve the realtime problem but means you have to change your schema to house a sum field for each filter.

Comment: @RodrigoDias This code is JavaScript. It is the code that the mongo console runs on. In  Ruby you would wrap your code blocks for each of the functions in `BSON::Code.new` and then call the actual MR like: `col.map_reduce(map, reduce,
            {
                :out => {:inline => true},
                :raw => true
            }
          )`

Comment: that's right, wrapped the map and reduce inside functions and called Mention.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, :query => {}) . thkss

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question, but without any answer.
So if you have only 2 possibilities for filter: facebook and twitter you can do this with two queries:

```
db.yourcollection.count({
  'filter' : 'facebook'
})
```

this will return you 1

```
db.yourcollection.count({
  'filter' : 'twitter'
})
```

this will return you 2

Comment: filter can be anything, it is a string

Comment: yes. it could return anything like: {facebook : 1203, twitter : 201, wherever : 200, othertype : 400}

Answer (score 0):

If you say that filter can be anything - than you should use mapreduce.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce

Here is a working code, put it in the mongo console, and than translate it to ruby.

first create map function:

```
var map = function(){
  emit(this.filter, 1);
}
```

reduce function:

```
var reduce = function(key, value){
  var n = 0;
  value.forEach(function(v){
     n+=v;
  });
  return n;
};
```

because you are using old version of mongo, you have to do the following:

```
res = db.runCommand({
  'mapreduce' : 'YOURCOLLECTION',
  'map' : map,
  'reduce' : reduce,
  'out' : 'tmp'
});
db.tmp.find();
```

this will return you

```
{'_id' : 'facebook', 'value' : 1},
{'_id' : 'twitter', 'value' : 2}
```